# How to clear notices when "proceed to checkout" in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, checkout

I am using the following code to add a notice on the cart page if the order has less than 1kg.

```php
// Add notice on cart when order is less than 1kg
add_action('woocommerce_check_cart_items','check_cart_minweight');
 
function check_cart_minweight(){
    global $woocommerce;

    $minweight = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_weight;

    if( $minweight < 1 ){ 
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( 'You have selected %sKg, add more items, orders over 1kg get free shipping', 'woocommerce' ), $minweight ), 'success' );
    }
}
```

The problem is that if the customer does not get over 1kg (many times they do not) and proceeds to checkout, the notice does not clear on checkout. Any advice to prevent this?

Comment: Have you tried to debug the value of `$minweight`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options. For example, you can ensure that your code is not executed on the checkout page:

```php
function action_woocommerce_check_cart_items() {
    // NOT for checkout page
    if ( is_checkout() ) return;

    // Get total weight
    $total_weight = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_weight();

    // Less
    if ( $total_weight < 1 ) { 
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( 'You have selected %sKg, add more items, orders over 1kg get free shipping', 'woocommerce' ), $total_weight ), 'notice' );
    }
}   
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items' , 'action_woocommerce_check_cart_items', 10 );
```

---

Another option is to make sure that the checkout page cannot be reached before the condition is met:

```php
function action_woocommerce_check_cart_items() {
    // Get total weight
    $total_weight = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_weight();

    // Less
    if ( $total_weight < 1 ) { 
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( 'You have selected %sKg, add more items, orders over 1kg get free shipping', 'woocommerce' ), $total_weight ), 'error' );

        // Remove proceed to checkout button
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );
    }
}   
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items' , 'action_woocommerce_check_cart_items', 10 );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function that does this here: https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/function/wc_clear_notices

```php
<?php wc_clear_notices(); ?>
```